# Structure of objects expected in series data

Tags: highcharts

I believe I am doing something wrong in the structure of the objects I am attempting to send to highcharts. I tried simplifying to an array of arrays, but am still doing something wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/rogerguess/H8vjR/2/

If I wanted to send highcharts a date, and two temperatures for a temp 'arearange'. What is the proper format of the series data?

```
var dataset = new Array();

function getData() {
    dataset.push([new Date(2013,9,1), 110, 68]);
    dataset.push([new Date(2013,9,2), 103, 71]);
    dataset.push([new Date(2013,9,3), 106, 69]);
};
```

Comment: Take a look the demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.highcharts` call your series item is an object, it should be in array of objects:

```
   series: [ // I added the left bracket
        {
          name: 'Temperatures',
          data: dataset

        }
    ] // and right bracket
```

I'd also rethink how you are creating that dataset array.  While it works, it's a bad practice to create throw away globals.  This is much cleaner:

```
function getData() {
    var dataset = new Array();
    dataset.push([Date.UTC(2013,9,1), 110, 68]);
    dataset.push([Date.UTC(2013,9,2), 103, 71]);
    dataset.push([Date.UTC(2013,9,3), 106, 69]);
    return dataset;
};

// in the above series use

data: getData();
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H8vjR/4/).

Comment: I just noticed the dates on the chart are showing as January 1st. Any idea why?

Comment: Roger, I didn't catch that.  Highcharts needs epoch milliseconds dates, not date objects.  Use `Date.UTC(2013,9,1)` etc...  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8vjR/5/